# How to encrypt a message with multiple public keys for multiple recipients

Tags: ethereumj, public-key, encryption, message

Is it possible to encrypt a message using multiple Ethereum public keys for multiple recipients of a message, e.g. using

https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto#encryptwithpublickey

, so that each recipient can decrypt the message with its private key?